# How to manage two search bar and dropdown box in Googlemap Javascript API

Tags: javascript, php, api

```
<div class="row">
            <table>
                <td>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <select class="form-control" name="companyID">
                            <option value="0">All companies</option>
                            </select>

                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="mapsearch" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" onclick="initAutocomplete()">
                </td>

            </table>

        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>

            function initialize(){

                initMap();
                initAutocomplete();
            }

            function initMap(){
                <?php
                    if($CompanyUserLocation) {
                        for($i=0; $i< count($CompanyUserLocation); $i++){
                            if(empty($fromLat[$i]) || empty($fromLon[$i])) {
                                continue;
                            }
                ?>
                            var options = {
                                zoom:10,
                                center:{
                                        lat: <?php echo $fromLat[$i]; ?>,
                                        lng: <?php echo $fromLon[$i]; ?> 
                                       }
                            }
                <?php } } ?>

                 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

                <?php 
                    for($i=0; $i< count($CompanyUserLocation); $i++){
                        if(empty($fromLat[$i]) || empty($fromLon{$i})) {
                                continue;
                            }
                ?>
                            var markers = [
                                {
                                coords:{
                                        lat: <?php echo $fromLat[$i];?>,
                                        lng: <?php echo $fromLon[$i];?>
                                    },  
                                content: '<h1><?php echo $CompanyUserName[$i]; ?></h1>'
                                }
                            ];
                        for(var i = 0;i < markers.length;i++){
                         // Add marker
                            addMarker(markers[i]);
                        }

                        function addMarker(props){
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position:props.coords,
                                map:map,
                              //icon:props.iconImage
                            });
                            // Check for customicon
                            if(props.iconImage){
                              // Set icon image
                                marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
                            }
                            // Check content
                            if(props.content){
                                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                    content:props.content
                                });
                                marker.addListener('click', function(){
                                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    <?php
                    } ?>

            }

         function initAutocomplete() {

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
              zoom: 13,

            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:{
                    lat: 27.72,
                    lng: 85.36
                },
                map:map

           });

            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('mapsearch'));
            google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function(){
                var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                var i, place;

                for(i=0; place=places[i];i++) {
                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                }

                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                map.setZoom(11);
            });
        }


          </script>
           <script  type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDK-vhUAcKLUzMWKbSzIxP2Wv3mZrsgNzE&language=de&libraries=places&callback=initialize"
     async defer></script>
```

I created search bar(for search google place address) and dropdown(for find the riders location) box dynamically. Now its worked. But its have some issue. 
That is,  If I search address in textbox, it showing the searched place. Its right. But after that, If i try to search in dropdown box for find the riders location, its displaying that place after double click an dropdown enter button.

As same as, if i first searched the riders location, its shown correct. But after that if i try to find google address in text box, autocomplete function is not working. what can I do? please help me. I am new for PHP and javascript.

Comment: You should also provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added my exact code for your knowledge. Please help me. Thanks for noticed my question.

Comment: I am not a `javascript` developer, I was given your question for review by StackOverflow. So I pointed out that you should also add your `code` to it. Hope your question gets answered soon :)